# How to find a word inside a list and search backwards from that word?

Tags: python, list

How can I search for a specific word inside a list? Once I have searched for that specific word, how can I search backwards from there? In my example, I need to search for the city, and then search backwards to find the street type (ex: Rd, St, Ave, etc.)

I first allow a user to input an address, like *123 Fakeville St SW San Francisco CA 90215*:

```
searchWord = 'San Francisco'
searchWord = searchWord.upper()
address = raw_input("Type an address: ").upper()
```

Once the address is entered, I split it using `address = address.split()`, which results in:

`['123', 'Fakeville', 'St', 'SW', 'San Francisco', 'CA', '90215']`

I then search for city in the list:

```
for items in address:
   if searchWord in items:
      print searchWord
```

But I'm not sure how to count backwards to find the street type (ex: St).

Comment: Are you doing any standardization to determine acceptable street types? What if the user omits it (common in some cities)? What of the situation you have in your example where 'SW' follows 'St'? You can get the index of any list element by using `i = address.index(searchWord)`, and then use slice/array notation to work backwards (`address[i-1]`).

Comment: Or don't use lists at all and rely on rfind.

Comment: Note, that splitting on your example string will rip apart `San` from `Francisco` so your expected output is not what it should be - think your original aim over again.

Comment: if your delimiter is space, then `San Francisco` are two items, not one

Comment: @Jan Didn't know, thanks for pointing it out. I tested it on a single word in my dev environment (ex: Boston) but thought of including a two word city here because I'll need that.

Comment: @Dan I was thinking of providing instructions on the proper way to enter the address. Let me try using `.index()` as you have suggested. edit: Seems to work for now, thanks. But only when the city is one word.

Comment: @mapr if you ask a user to enter an integer they will enter "cheeseburger". You need to validate input. Perhaps prompt for address #, street name, street type, city, etc. separately

Comment: `address = address.split()` would result in `['123', 'Fakeville', 'St', 'SW', 'San', 'Francisco', 'CA', '90215']` so `'San Francisco'` wouldn't be found by your `for` loop at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list.index` method to search the index of an item in a list.

There is no `list.rindex` method to search backward.
You need to use:

```
rev_idx = len(my_list) - my_list[::-1].index(item) - 1
```

I don't really understand what’s your aim, be I can explain how to search backward the "St" string in the *address* list of strings:

```
address = ['123', 'Fakeville', 'St', 'SW', 'San Francisco', 'CA', '90215']

town_idx = address.index('San Francisco')
print(town_idx)
# You'll get: 4

before = address[:town_idx]
st_index = len(before) - before[::-1].index("St") - 1
print(st_index)
# You'll get: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for items in address:
    if searchWord in items:
        for each in reversed(address[0:address.index(searchWord)]):
            if each == 'St':
                print each
```

Once you find the city, reverse traverse the list using reversed